# RVM not working after installing properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, path, rvm, bash

Ok so I had RVM working before but after I upgraded to Mountain Lion it appears to be gone? So I tried reinstalling it:

```
Ayman$ curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   185  100   185    0     0    200      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   755
100  9979  100  9979    0     0   5911      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  5911  
Downloading RVM from wayneeseguin branch stable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   125  100   125    0     0     67      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   102
100 1047k  100 1047k    0     0   159k      0  0:00:06  0:00:06 --:--:--  245k

Upgrading the RVM installation in /Users/Ayman/.rvm/
RVM PATH line found in /Users/Ayman/.zshrc.
RVM sourcing line found in /Users/Ayman/.zlogin.

Upgrade Notes:

  * No new notes to display.

# RVM:  Shell scripts enabling management of multiple ruby environments.
# RTFM: https://rvm.io/
# HELP: http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=rvm (#rvm on irc.freenode.net)
# Cheatsheet: http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/rvm/
# Screencast: http://screencasts.org/episodes/how-to-use-rvm

# In case of any issues read output of 'rvm requirements' and/or 'rvm notes'

Upgrade of RVM in /Users/Ayman/.rvm/ is complete.

# Ayman ####,
#
#   Thank you for using RVM!
#   I sincerely hope that RVM helps to make your life easier and more enjoyable!!!
#
# ~Wayne


rvm 1.15.5 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis    <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

Should be installed right? Should be ready to go but...

```
Ayman$ which rvm
Ayman$ rvm requirements
-bash: rvm: command not found
Ayman$ rvm use 1.9.2 --default
-bash: rvm: command not found
```

Now sure what to do? Looked at my .bash_profile and .bashrc to see what's there:

```
Ayman$ ls -la
total 136
drwxr-xr-x+ 26 Ayman  staff    884 Aug 23 20:44 .
drwxr-xr-x   6 root   admin    204 Aug  8 19:27 ..
-rw-------   1 Ayman  staff      3 Jun 16 15:21 .CFUserTextEncoding
-rw-r--r--@  1 Ayman  staff  21508 Aug 23 08:03 .DS_Store
drwx------  10 Ayman  staff    340 Aug 23 07:57 .Trash
-rw-------   1 Ayman  staff   9089 Aug 23 20:47 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--   1 Ayman  staff    106 Aug 22 21:17 .bash_profile
-rw-r--r--   1 Ayman  staff     24 Aug 23 20:47 .bashrc
drwxr-xr-x   3 Ayman  staff    102 Aug 21 20:41 .bundler
drwxr-xr-x   3 Ayman  staff    102 Jun 24 21:45 .gem
-rw-r--r--   1 root   staff    155 Aug 21 22:52 .gemrc
-rw-r--r--   1 Ayman  staff     61 Aug 21 19:40 .gitconfig
-rw-r--r--   1 Ayman  staff     14 Aug 23 08:14 .irb_history
-rw-------   1 Ayman  staff   2415 Aug 23 20:44 .mysql_history
drwxr-xr-x  29 Ayman  staff    986 Aug 23 20:58 .rvm
-rw-r--r--   1 Ayman  staff    118 Jun 24 21:25 .zlogin
-rw-r--r--   1 Ayman  staff     59 Jun 24 21:25 .zshrc
drwx------+ 18 Ayman  staff    612 Aug 23 08:02 Desktop
drwx------+  5 Ayman  staff    170 Jun 24 23:04 Documents
drwx------+ 19 Ayman  staff    646 Aug 22 21:05 Downloads
drwx------@ 47 Ayman  staff   1598 Aug  9 22:30 Library
drwx------+  3 Ayman  staff    102 Jun 16 15:21 Movies
drwx------+  5 Ayman  staff    170 Jun 24 23:05 Music
drwx------+ 57 Ayman  staff   1938 Aug 19 22:40 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x+  5 Ayman  staff    170 Jun 16 15:21 Public
drwxr-xr-x   5 Ayman  staff    170 Aug 23 07:57 Sites
```

Here is my nano .bashprofile:

```
PS1="\u$ "
alias ll="ls -lahG"

export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
```

Here is my nano .bashrc (I changed it per instructions in another stackoverflow answer):

```
PATH=$PATH:~/.rvm/bin
```

Any clue as to what to try next? Thanks!

Comment: Have you done "source .bashrc"? It seems rvm is still out of your system path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

to force update of rc files:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --auto-dotfiles
```

Answer (score -1):

Mac OS runs .bash_profile but not .bash_rc when you create a new terminal. Move those PATH things into .bash_profile and run again.

As to your second problem, seems you add wrong things into PATH. Add followings into .bash_profile:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/scripts # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
. rvm > /dev/null
```

Comment: Thank you @waitingkuo! 

Here is my nano .bash_profile 


   PS1="\u$ "
   alias ll="ls -lahG"

   export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH:~/.rvm/b$

Comment: It's better that modify you tags and then add something like osx, path, or bash_profile. That might help other people can find the right way faster.

Comment: @waitingkua Actually... just tried using RVM and I got the following error: `Ayman$ rvm use 1.9.2

RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.
You need to change your terminal settings to allow shell login.
Please visit https://rvm.io/workflow/screen/ for example.`

Comment: Thanks for the edited answer @waitingkuo. Everything is working flawlessly now.

Comment: this is wrong, `.rvm/scripts` should not be in PATH, it should be `source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm` and in .bashrc `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin` - see my answer for proper fix!